# Add files deleted on second remote back

Tags: git

I have two remote git repositories, A and B. B should contain all the files that are in A, and might contain additional files.
Adding new files from A to B works fine, but I encounter a problem in the following situation:

1. In the beginning, A and B contain the same set of files: `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.
2. Then, somebody accidentally deletes `file1` and `file2` from repo B and pushes the changes. This person also creates a new file `fileB` in repo B.
3. At the same time, `file4` is created in repo A.
4. I run a script, that is supposed to synchronize A and B. From a branch in B I run: `git merge <branch in A> -X theirs`. After merging, B contains only files `file3`, `file4` and `fileB`, the deleted files aren't added to B again.

I'm looking for a way to upload all the files from A to B again in case they get deleted in B. Merge conflicts occur only if I modify files in A, then I can just run

```
git checkout <branch in B>
git merge <branch in A> -X theirs // <- merge conflict
git add -A
git commit -m 'resolve conflict'
git push
```

In this case deleted files `file1` and `file2` return to B. Is there any way to add them back to B without modifying them and without force pushing from A to B (that would delete new files in B)?

Comment: You don't *accidentally* remove files from repo. If someone deletes files in repo B just revert theirs commit. `--theis` merge strategy is just for conflict resolution.

Comment: @mx0 that would require managing all the repositories manually, which I'd like to avoid, it would take really a lot of time to check what is deleted and why.